# Update a scope after each one of multiple ajax request with angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want create a simple modal where I would like to output the result of a series of multiple ajax requests.

The script should do this: after a button click, open a modal, make an ajax request, show the output of the request in the modal, make another ajax request, update the modal message and go on and on...

I have tried with a service where I make the ajax request, but not sure if this is the best solution...

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JySrMYocYGtCvftHLw4G?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can use `service` only to call `$http` that should return `promise`. The `then` callback should be implemented into controller and not in `service` like you implemented.

Something like:

```
myModule.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',  function(_http) {   

var path = 'src/php/data.ajax.php';

return{
    init: function(jsonData){
        var _promise= _http.post(path, 
            jsonData
            ,{
                headers: {
                    'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                }
            }
            );            
        return _promise; 
    } 
  }   
}]);
```

and now you can call in controller:

```
ajax_post.init(jsonData);
```

And your "chain" of promises in controller should be like:

```
var promise = asyncFunction(parameters);

promise.then(function (result) {
  return otherAsyncFunction(result * 2);
}).then(function(result) {

if (result < 0) { throw "Some Error" };
  return mayBeSyncOrAsyncFunction(result);
}).then(function(result) {
  console.log("Final Result: " + result);
}, function(error) {
// Handle error (exception, etc).
});
```

The other good way is to use `$q`:

If you want to wait for multiple promises

`$q.all([promise, …])` → *newPromise*

*newPromise* will resolve once all the given promises have 
been resolved
If any of the given promises is rejected, *newPromise* will 
also be rejected